# Is it appropriate to fit a linear model to my data?

Tags: regression, linear-model, outliers, polynomial

I have a bunch of outcome/exposure relationships I am trying to fit models to: [image]

From these graphs, I am not sure if a simple `lm` is appropriate. Some of them look like there could be some curvature (but not sustained- maybe the loess is capturing local noise). Should I be adding a quadratic term?

Also, there appear to be some outliers that could affect a linear model. I examined the outliers and they are real so I guess I could try removing them and refitting or maybe try robust regression?

I don't have much experience looking at these sorts of graphs, so is my interpretation appropriate and how should I best move forward? Thank you!

Comment: Can you fit a straight line through the confidence bands on the curves?

Comment: I can recommend chapter 7 here https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf (and the book itself).

Comment: @Alexis I think so! I didn't really think about that